# Reindex Pandas DataFrame with interpolated values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a pandas DataFrame with a DateTimeIndex and the columns "Threshold", "Path":

```py
                             Path  Threshold
2020-12-11 04:00:25.729  0.000104  -1.107422
2020-12-11 04:00:25.731  0.000387  -1.107422
2020-12-11 04:00:25.733  0.000899  -1.107422
2020-12-11 04:00:25.735  0.001561  -1.117676
2020-12-11 04:00:25.737  0.002272  -1.117676
...                           ...        ...
2020-12-11 04:01:03.063  9.085985  -1.209961
2020-12-11 04:01:03.065  9.085985  -1.209961
2020-12-11 04:01:03.067  9.085985  -1.209961
2020-12-11 04:01:03.069  9.085985  -1.199707
2020-12-11 04:01:03.071  9.085985  -1.199707
```

Now I want to create a new DataFrame that is indexed on a linearly spaced version of "Path", i.e.

```py
>>> np.arange(df["Path"].min(), df["Path"].max(), 0.05)
array([1.040000e-04, 5.010400e-02, 1.001040e-01, 1.501040e-01,
       2.001040e-01, 2.501040e-01, ...
```

The values from "Path" are monotonic (but not strictly monotonic). As a column for this new DataFrame I want to set the appropriately interpolated values from "Threshold", however with pandas' `interpolate` and numpy's `interp` methods I didn't manage to achieve this. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: If is used only sample data in question how is expected output? Whats happen with duplicated values in `Path` ?

Comment: @jezrael This doesn't really matter to me, I guess just dropping any duplicates from ```Path``` would be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is use [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```
a = np.arange(df["Path"].min(), df["Path"].max(), 0.05)

df1 = pd.merge_asof(df.reset_index(), 
                    pd.DataFrame({'new':a}), 
                    left_on='Path', 
                    right_on='new', 
                    direction='nearest')
```

Another idea with removed duplicated and [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df2 = (df.drop_duplicates('Path')
         .reset_index()
         .set_index('Path')
         .reindex(a, method='nearest'))
```

Comment: While both of your ideas worked your second one brings me even closer to what I need to continue. Thank you!